# How to verify whether HTML controls exist from code behind

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an asp.net form.

But the controls inside the form at 1 textbox and 2 dropdown lists as a row.

And there is a "plus" and "minus" buttons for users to add in and delete the rows.

When the form is submitted, I will grab the values from those controls by using `Request.Form["ControlName"]`

But I need to confirm whether that `["ControlName"]` exists.

I can put that piece of code in `try catch` to confirm like this

```
for(int a=1;a<10;a++)
{
  try 
  {
    Response.Write(Request.Form["ControlName"+a.ToString()]);
  }
  catch {}
}
```

By doing this, the controls which don't exist will be catched by catch statement in theory.

But I am trying to use another method to do the checking like `FindControl("ServerControlID")`

But that one is for the `server controls` only.

My front code will be something like this

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1"/>

<input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2"/>

<input type="text" id="txt4" name="txt3"/>
```

NOTE : I cannot add in `runat="server"`. If so, I can use `FindControl()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a control on server side (code behind), than that control must be a server control or even an html control but with `runat = "server"` attribute, by introducing you can access the HTML control.

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" runat = "server"/>
```

Comment: I m sorry. I do not own the front part.So, I can't add change `HTML Control` to `HTML Server Control`

Comment: As far as my little knowledge is in place, I am afraid you won't be able to do it than.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `NameValueCollection` returned by `Request.Form.AllKeys`.
This returns an `IEnumerable`

Use Linq to check it as follows:

```
for(int a=1;a<10;a++)
{
  var paramName = "ControlName"+a.ToString();
  if(Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(paramName ))
  {
    Response.Write(Request.Form[paramName ]);
  }
  else
  {
    //key not present
  }
}
```